# Cordova project with sub project build fails

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm currently developing a Cordova based iOS app. I want to add `VK` social network SDK to the project. Their doc requires to add the project as a subproject to the main project.

The problem is that the subproject of `VK` has its own bundle identifier which is `com.vk.VKSdkFramework` which is of course different from my project bundle id.

When I run `cordova build ios --device`, I get the following error:

```
=== BUILD TARGET VKSdkFramework OF PROJECT VK-ios-sdk WITH 
CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
Code Sign error: Provisioning profile does not match bundle identifier: 
The provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“iPhone 4s”) 
has an AppID of “com.myappid” which does not match your bundle 
identifier “com.vk.VKSdkFramework”.
```

It builds as expected in Xcode but not Cordova. Is there a way to ignore this check for bundle id?

Comment: why dont you try readymade plugins like https://github.com/akveo/cordova-vk  https://github.com/DrMoriarty/cordova-social-vk

Comment: I'm already using the plugin but it needs to be updated to the new VK iOS SDK or it will fail to build